# How to create a second type of tables, with a different label-name

Tags: tables, tabularx, counters

Currently I am working on a file, that already contains a lot of tables, that are all well set with `ltablex`. In only one of the chapters.

I'm going to add tables which will only be descriptions of testcases, but in form of a table. I want to set the table-labels of those special tables to **"Testcase N: XXX"**. Also they should start counting at 1.

In the following chapters the tabels should wear the usual Table label und continue the orginal table counter.

Is there a possibility to create a second type of tables and only define there label? e.g.

```
\begin{myOwnTable}
\end{myOwnTable}
```

that should be a clone of the original tabularx environment but with a different label and own counting variable.

If it is possible, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The float package can define new types:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{Testcase}{htbp}{test}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{Testcase} 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
aaa & bbbb\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{text}
\end{Testcase}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer `myOwnTable` environment, the caption package can be used to change the caption to `testcase`